# Check if a dictionary has a particular value in it and insert a new item after the matching value to it

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, and i am trying to check if each individual dictionaries in the list contain a particular value and then if the value matches, insert a new item to the matching dictionary.

```
emp_name = "Jack"
my_list =  [{'name':'Jack', 'age':'42', 'j_id':'1'}, {'name':'charles', 'age':'32', 'j_id':'34'}, {'name':'john', 'age':'44', 'j_id':'3'}, {'name':'jacob', 'age':'24', 'j_id':'5'}]
for item in my_list:
    name = item.get('name')
    print(name)
    if name == emp_name:
        item['date'] = "something"
        print(item)
        # add this item value to the dictionary
    else:
        print("not_matching")
```

---

**Here is my expected output:**

```
[{'name':'Jack', 'age':'42', 'j_id':'1', 'date':'something'}, 
{'name':'charles', 'age':'32', 'j_id':'34'}, {'name':'john', 'age':'44', 
'j_id':'3'}, {'name':'jacob', 'age':'24', 'j_id':'5'}]
```

Is there any other pythonic way to simplify this code?

Comment: And ? What do you mean " i am stuck here adding the new value corresponding to the matching value in the dictionary." ? Running your code yields the exact expected result.

Comment: i tested somethimg in my code and then edited my question later...

Comment: Then you obviously didn't bother editing it so it could make sense. If your question is only "how can I improve this code" then you should have removed the "I'm still here... stuck" part and the expected results. Thanks for wasting readers time...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of the `for` loop.

```py
for item in my_list:
    if 'name' in item and item['name'] == emp_name:
        item['date'] = 'something'
```

**EDIT:** Alternate solution (as suggested by @brunodesthuilliers below) - is to use dict's `get()` method (more details in comments section below).

```py
for item in my_list:
    if item.get("name", "") == emp_name:
        item['date'] = 'something'
```

Comment: Use `dict.get()` => `if item.get("name", "") == emp_name;`

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers for the suggestion! This is a question for my understanding and knowledge - since I'm already checking for the key (name) in dict, will using `[]` than `get()` give better result, performance or otherwise?

Comment: The point of using `dict.get()` is more about readability than raw performances actually - wrt/ perfs, it seems that your solution is a bit faster (measured with `timeit`) so it might indeed be better if you're in a tight loop, but then you may want to try other optimization strategies before (ie using a dict of `name:list_of_dicts_for_this_name` instead of a list of dicts)

Comment: Understood, interesting points! With your permission, I am updating the answer and adding your suggestion.